# Obtain the SUM from a column by ID from a table that isn't normalized?

Tags: mysql, sum, database-normalization

I have a database from a hospital. In a table there's 1 or more transaction numbers and almost all of them only contain 1 Doctor ID. The table hasn't been normalized yet.

The data looks like the following:

```
Trans_No    |Doctor_ID  |Trans_Type                     |PM |Cost
10.853329   |           |ADMINISTRASI                   |   |0.00
10.853329   |10004      |JASA MEDIS                     |   |25000.00
10.853329   |           |OBAT RESEP FARMASI NO : 1077   |F  |2000.00
10.836033   |           |ADMINISTRASI                   |   |0.00
10.836033   |10001      |JASA MEDIS                     |   |25000.00
10.836033   |           |OBAT RESEP FARMASI NO : 3137   |F  |0.00
10.836032   |           |ADMINISTRASI                   |   |0.00
10.836032   |10001      |JASA MEDIS                     |   |25000.00
10.836032   |           |OBAT RESEP FARMASI NO : 3138   |F  |10000.00
```

How can I get doctor ID and the SUM of cost from that doctor where the PM column value is F?

I can't change the database because it already has more than a hundred thousand transactions.

Comment: A few hundred thousand transactions is not a reason to stop normalisation. If your table needs to be normalised (and it does) then just do it.

Comment: from your given example, what is the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery to create a "table" mapping Trans_No to Doctor_ID.  Then join your real table with this subquery to have a Doctor_ID for every transaction row.  Then you can do your `WHERE` and `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT tdoc.Doctor_ID, SUM(Cost) FROM your_table
JOIN (
  SELECT Trans_No, Doctor_ID FROM your_table WHERE Doctor_ID <> ''
  GROUP BY Trans_No, Doctor_ID
) tdoc ON tdoc.Trans_No = your_table.Trans_No
WHERE PM = 'F'
GROUP BY tdoc.Doctor_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives you a normalized version of Trans_No, Doctor_ID, and Cost:

```
select
  Trans_No,
  max(Doctor_ID) as Doctor_ID,
  max(case when PM="F" then Cost end) as Cost
from
  your_table
group by
  Trans_No
```

then you have to group by Doctor_ID:

```
Select Doctor_ID, sum(Cost)
From (
  select
    Trans_No,
    max(Doctor_ID) as Doctor_ID,
    max(case when PM="F" then Cost end) as Cost
  from
    your_table
  group by
    Trans_No) your_table
Group by Doctor_ID
```